# Printing arrays in Java by Counter

Tags: java, arrays

This java program is supposedly print the numbers in the array below:

```
public class Masterpiece {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int laser[] = new int[10];

        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 10 numbers.");

        for (int counter = 0; counter < laser.length; counter++) {
            System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
            laser[counter] = x.nextInt();
        }

        Arrays.sort(laser);

        for (int counter = 9; counter <= 0; counter--) {
            System.out.println(laser[counter]); /** line 21 */
        }

        System.out.println("Highest: " + laser[9]);
        System.out.println("Lowest: " + laser[0]);
    }
}
```

However, at line 21, it doesn't print the array elements. Why?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop is counting backwards, but your conditional portion of the loop (`counter <= 0`) is checking if `counter` is less than or equal to 0. Since you start the `counter` at 9, this condition immediately fails because it is not less than or equal to 0 and no code within the loop is executed. You want greater than or equal to 0:

```
for (int counter = 9; counter >= 0; counter--) {
```

I would also suggest you use the length of the array here too so that if you ever adjust the size, you won't have to modify the loop code:

```
for (int counter = laser.length; counter >= 0; counter--) {
```

Comment: Actually, you didn't tell the OP why line 21 doesn't print the array element. It is because the loop header is wrong so the loop doesn't get executed. That is the main point.

Comment: @Sweeper Agreed, I've added an explanation as to why.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int counter = 9; counter >= 0; counter--) {
    System.out.println(laser[counter]);
}
```

But usually it is better if you stick to the standard forms:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < laser.length; counter++) {
    System.out.println(laser[counter]);
}
```

Or, it is better to use the *enhanced for structure*:

```
for (int val : laser) {
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop you initialize counter to 9 and tell the loop to execute when 9 less than or equal to 0 and then you subtract one. The problem is that when the program first gets to the for loop 9 is not less than 0 so the value is false and it skips the loop.

A better loop would be:

```
    For(int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++)
    {
        System.out.println(laser[counter]);
    }
```